# Why does the if and elif function not work properly in my code

Tags: python

I am very much a beginner in code. I have made this code (this is an abridged version) for my homework assignment but whenever I press play and start the process, no matter what number of sides I input, it always asks for a number of parallel sides and then guesses and isosceles triangle. Why is this the case?

```
print("Shape Guesser Game \n-----------------")
print("Welcome to the Shape Guesser Game! \nI believe that I can guess the shape you think of.")
print("There is only 1 rule: \nYou can only think of a polygon with a maximum of 6 sides.")
response_1 = input("\nDo you want to play? \nPick Yes or No")
if response_1 == "Yes" or "yes":
    print("Great! Let's get started! \n------------------")
    response_2 = input("Have you thought of your shape? Yes/No")
    if response_2 == "Yes" or "yes":
        response_3 = input("How many sides does it have?")
        if response_3 == "3" or "three":
            response_4 = input("How many equal sides does it have?")
            if response_4 == "2" or "two":
                response_5 = input("Aha! It is an isosceles triangle! Am I right? Yes or No?")
                if response_5 == "yes" or "Yes":
                    print("Yay I have succeeded! Thank you for playing this game. \nGo back to Home.")

            elif response_4 == "3" or "three":
                response_6 = input("Aha! It is an equilateral triangle! Am I right? Yes or No?")
                print("Yay I have succeeded! Thank you for playing this game. \nGo back to Home.")

            else:
                print("Not valid:Error \n-------------")

        elif response_3 == "4" or "four":
            response_7 = input("How many parallel sides does it have?")
            if response_7 == "two" or "2":
                response_8 = input("Aha! It is a trapezium! Am I right? Yes or No?")
                if response_8 == "yes" or "Yes":
                    print("Yay I have succeeded! Thank you for playing this game. \nGo back to Home.")
            if response_7 == "four" or "4":
                response_9 = input("Aha! It is a parallelogram! Am I right? Yes or No?")
                if response_9 == "yes" or "Yes":
                    print("Yay I have succeeded! Thank you for playing this game. \nGo back to Home.")

    elif response_2 == "No" or "no":
        print("Okay no worries, I will give you more time!")

elif response_1 == "No" or "no":
    print("Sad to see you go! Back to Home.")
```

Comment: In addition to fixing `if response_1 == "Yes" or "yes"` by changing it to `if response_1 == "Yes" or response_1 == "yes"`, you can also check multiple things with `if` as `if response_1 in ("Yes", "yes")`. This can be nice when you need to compare against several values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have the same issue in each of your if statements. When you write something like

```
if response_1 == "Yes" or "yes"
```

python interprets this as

```
if (response_1 == "Yes") or ("yes")
```

That is: if the variable response_1 is equal to "Yes", or if the string "yes" is truthy, then the if statement runs. "yes" is truthy, so the if statement always runs. (See [here](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html) for example for more information about what truthiness means).

What you probably wanted was to check if the variable response_1 is equal to "Yes" or if it's equal to "yes", which is written as:

```
if response_1 == "Yes" or response_1 == "yes"`
```

And of course you'll need to apply this same correction to the rest of your if statements as well.

Comment: AHHH i get it now!! Thank you so much:))))

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
print("Shape Guesser Game \n-----------------")
print("Welcome to the Shape Guesser Game! \nI believe that I can guess the shape you think of.")
print("There is only 1 rule: \nYou can only think of a polygon with a maximum of 6 sides.")
response_1 = input("\nDo you want to play? \nPick Yes or No")
if response_1.lower() == "yes":
    print("Great! Let's get started! \n------------------")
    response_2 = input("Have you thought of your shape? Yes/No")
    if response_2.lower() == "yes":
        response_3 = input("How many sides does it have?")
        if response_3 == "3" or response_3 == "three":
            response_4 = input("How many equal sides does it have?")
            if response_4 == "2" or response_4 == "two":
                response_5 = input("Aha! It is an isosceles triangle! Am I right? Yes or No?")
                if response_5.lower() == "yes":
                    print("Yay I have succeeded! Thank you for playing this game. \nGo back to Home.")

            elif response_4 == "3" or response_4 == "three":
                response_6 = input("Aha! It is an equilateral triangle! Am I right? Yes or No?")
                print("Yay I have succeeded! Thank you for playing this game. \nGo back to Home.")

            else:
                print("Not valid:Error \n-------------")

        elif response_3 == "4" or response_3 == "four":
            response_7 = input("How many parallel sides does it have?")
            if response_7 == "two" or response_7 == "2":
                response_8 = input("Aha! It is a trapezium! Am I right? Yes or No?")
                if response_8.lower() == "yes":
                    print("Yay I have succeeded! Thank you for playing this game. \nGo back to Home.")
            if response_7 == "four" or response_7 == "4":
                response_9 = input("Aha! It is a parallelogram! Am I right? Yes or No?")
                if response_9.lower() == "yes":
                    print("Yay I have succeeded! Thank you for playing this game. \nGo back to Home.")

    elif response_2.lower() == "no":
        print("Okay no worries, I will give you more time!")

elif response_1.lower() == "no":
    print("Sad to see you go! Back to Home.")
```

`or` doesn't work just like `if a == 'b' or 'c':`, you have to make it `if a == 'b' or a == 'c':`

Also stuff like `if response_1 == "Yes" or "yes"` that can just become `if response_1.lower() == "yes"`, so `YeS` and `yEs` would be considered `'yes'`.

Comment: I was able to solve it! Thank you so much:)))

Comment: @JuihiCharadva If it works, please accept it